# How to construct multiple bar plots overlaying rows with a data frame that has incidence matrix structure

Tags: r, igraph, adjacency-matrix, cptbarplot

For the follwoing data that represents the flow of the tourist by months for these five countries, I would like to draw a multiple bar plot such that one row of the mutliple bar plot represents the flow of tourists for a certain country for 12 months and on the top of it, the next row represents the flow of tourists for another country for 12 months and so on.

consider a follwoing data (tourist flow in millions):

```
set.seed(19881003)
Australia <- (runif(12,0,1))
France <- (runif(12, 0,1) + Australia)
UnitedKingdom <- rbinom(12,2, 0.6)
USA <- rpois(12,0.06)+UnitedKingdom
Italy <- UnitedKingdom+USA+0.012
months <- c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov","Dec")
#
tourist.data <- data.frame(months, Australia, France, UnitedKingdom, USA, Italy)
```

It would be great if you could plot mutliple bar plot such that countries are plotted on x axis and months are plotted on y-axis. One row should represent the tourist flow of a particular country for 12 months. The other row on the top of it represents the bar plot of the tourist flow of a another country for the same 12 months.

It would also be great if I could choose to order the country (i.e, which country to plot at the bottom, followed by the choosen countries at top).

Would be very grateful if anyone could help me with this.

Multiple bar plots of the data frame with adjajency matrix could be plotted with the help of igraph package to by determinging edges and vertices. But I have no idea of how it could be done with data frame that has incidence matrix structure.
Thanks

Comment: please give an example to show how the desired plot looks like

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding In reply to this, I have provided an example of tourist flow data from one country to another country It is a kind of adjacency matrix of which I have made a bar plot. However, I need a bar plot of tourist flow data of countries across months which I could not prepare in similar way

Answer (score 0):

To be precise I can provide an example of the multiple bar plot for the following data frame with adjacency structure.
Consider the following data frame that represents the flow of tourists from one country to another from among 5 countries.

```
set.seed(19881003)
Australia <- (runif(5,0,1))
France <- (runif(5, 0,1) + Australia)
UnitedKingdom <- rbinom(5,2, 0.6)
USA <- rpois(5,0.06)+UnitedKingdom
Italy <- UnitedKingdom+USA+0.012
country <- c("Australia", "France", "UnitedKingdom", "USA", "Italy")
touristflow <- data.frame(country, Australia, France, UnitedKingdom, USA, Italy)

library(tidyr)
main_data<- pivot_longer(touristflow,cols=c("Australia", "France", "UnitedKingdom", "USA","Italy"),
                   names_to = "dest_country", values_to = "tourist_flow (in millions)")
## Also prepare a dataframe of vertices and other attributes
support_data<- data.frame(region = 
                     c("Australia",
                       "France",
                       "UnitedKingdom",
                       "USA", "Italy"),
                 order1 = c(1,2,3,4,5),
                 col1 = c("#40A4D8","#33BEB7","#B2C224",
                     "#FECC2F", "#FBA127"),
                 reg1 = c("Australia","France",
                           "UnitedKingdom",
                              "USA", "Italy"),
                 reg2 = c("","","","",""))

## prepare for chart
svg_file <- "multiplebarplot.svg"
svg(svg_file, width=10, height=12)

library(igraph)
library(RColorBrewer)
## 
## prepare data
flowdat <- graph_from_data_frame(d=main_data, vertices = support_data,
                                 directed = TRUE)
flowdat_mat <- get.adjacency(flowdat, attr = "tourist_flow (in millions)", sparse = FALSE) 
maxmvalue <- max(flowdat_mat)
n <- nrow(flowdat_mat)
m <- n
##
par(mfrow = c(n,m), omi = c(1,4,4,2), mai=c(0,0,0,0))
color1 <- rgb(255,0,210, maxColorValue = 255)
color2 <- rgb(0,208,226, maxColorValue = 255)

## chart
for (i in 1:n) {
    for (j in 1:m) {
        plot (1:1, xlim= c(0,1), ylim = c(0,1), type = "n", axes = FALSE)
        if (i<j) mycolor <- color1
        if (i==j) mycolor <- "grey80"
        if (i>j) mycolor <- color2
        if(i==1) text(0.5, 1.2,support_data$region[j],
                      cex=2, xpd=NA, adj=0, srt=45,col=color1)
        if(j==1) text(-0.1, 0.5, support_data$region[i],
                      cex=2, xpd=NA, adj=1, col=color2)
        rect(0,0,1,1, col="grey95", border=NA)
        rect(0,0,1,flowdat_mat[i,j]/maxmvalue, col=mycolor,
             border=NA)
        text(0.5,0.5,format(round(flowdat_mat[i,j],2), nsmall=2), cex=1.5,
             col="grey40")
       
    }
}
mtext("Flow to:",side=3, outer = TRUE, cex=2.5, line=14, col=mycolor1, adj=0)
mtext("Tourist Flow (in millions)", side=3, outer = TRUE, cex=3, adj=1, at=0.4, line = 22, col="grey50", family="Lato Black")

dev.off()
```

I have also attached the output. I need similar output of countries but across months (not country to country)
Hope this information helps[image: Multiple Bar Plot]